# c++ - interface for type conversion, not cast

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

This is a bit hard to explain, but I'll try my best. Let's say we have a function that will receive an option. That option would be, in the very first time, a string. Something like this:

> command option="blah blah blah"

Here, our option would have been `blah blah blah`.

Now, I want to provide the developer a way to "convert" (**not cast**) the string into another type. I would implement my own "translators" for basic types, such as `bool` or `int`, for instance:

> command recursive="true"

or

> command lines=7

letting the developer override them or specify new ones, maybe with functors (as I'm using C++11, there's no problem in using wonderful `functional`).

The problem is that I haven't still found an acceptable idea about how to implement this. I've tried some things according to my knowledge of C++ -which is definitely not "complete", but "acceptable"- but many of them just didn't work or got me stuck. I mean I can go with some dirty tricks but I'd like the most elegant solution for this (of course type-safe).

I hope I'm not being a *luser* with you. Thanks for your time, and sorry in any case.

Best regards,
Kalrish

Comment: [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) - don't let the name fool you. It does what you're looking for.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I'm sorry - boost is sadly not an option in the environment I'm working on. Sorry for not pointing that out. Thanks in any case.

Comment: Well, good luck reinventing the wheel then. Make sure nobody who's paying you notices :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it must not be that difficult to implement type converters. In fact, and as I have pointed out, I want to let the developer change the "conversor" that is being used by explicitly overriding it via a `std::function`. If the developer uses boost, then it's OK for him/her. I can just not use boost, those are my limitations.

Comment: Well, you need a parser...

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a string to an integer you can start with using [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

```
std::string strValue = "1245";
int intValue = atoi(strValue.c_str());
```

Or in C++11 you can use

```
int intValue = std::atoi(strValue.c_str());
```

To convert to a bool you can start by just comparing the string

```
bool boolValue = strValue == "true";
```

Comment: Why are you using `?:` to convert a boolean value to the same boolean value? Also, in C++11 that would be `std::stoi(strValue)`

Comment: @MikeSeymour because `string::compare` returns an `int` not a `bool`

Comment: But you're comparing it to 0, giving the boolean value you need. Why do you think you need the `?:` dance on top of that? For that matter, why not use `strValue == "true"` if you want an equality comparison?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Simple avoiding warnings for forcing an `int` to a `bool`. I generally enable options for warnings as errors so it's habit to avoid the warnings.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ack! Gotcha now, Thanks. Updated

Comment: But you wouldn't be forcing an int to a bool. The expression `strValue == "true"` (or `0 == strValue.compare("true")` if you insist on obfuscating it) is boolean; there's no need for a further conversion to `bool`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah I saw that right after I posted the comment. Very nice Doh! moment.